# ball Solid geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Can you Please help me with finding solution. Thank you!

The ball intersects by a plane, whose diameter from the center of the ball is seen as 120 degrees. Find in what relation this plane intersects the volume. And find relation, what respect this plane intersects the area of ​​the sphere.

Comment: I do not understand the second sentence.

Comment: Q1: plane/Volume of ball. Q2: plane/Sphere Area.